# How to disable Mule's IMAP inbound endpoint with property

Tags: java, mule, imap

I have IMAP inbound endpoint in my Mule instance, for some email processing. Is it possible somehow to disable/enable it with property? For example, I would put email.service.enabled=true/false as a property, and than in the flow, I would check if property is true or false before initialising IMAP inbound endpoint.

If I put check at the beginning of the flow, I am getting exception, because inbound endpoint needs to be at the top of the flow.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is very much possible .. for example in your properties file the value is as following :-

```
email.service.enabled=true
```

Now, in your Mule flow, you can pick the value from the properties file in a message property transformer as follows :-

```
<message-properties-transformer scope="outbound" doc:name="Message Properties">
  <add-message-property key="email.service.enabled" value="${email.service.enabled}"/>
</message-properties-transformer>
```

Then use a **message-property-filter** before your smtp to check the value of email.service.enabled

```
 <message-property-filter pattern="email.service.enabled=true" caseSensitive="true" doc:name="Message Property"/>
```

... if the value is **true**, then the **payload passed** and you can send **mail** or else if it is **false**, then no mail is send ...

This is how you can disable/enable it with property

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I am not sure if I explained well, but I am not trying to send email via Mule, I am using IMAP inbound endpoint to receive email. Inbound endpoint needs to be initialised at the beginning of the flow, otherwise I am getting exceptions. What I need to achieve is to check for property before flow initialisation. Thanks

Comment: If you need to load the property from an external file to initialize and set disable/enable it with property you can follow the example given above and modify it as per your requirement